# axis.set_xlim is setting the same limit for all the subplots

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, seaborn

I was plotting some data I was trying to study. By trying to create subplots to compact the graphs, I encountered a problem, **the x limits are the same for all the graphs**, even if I am supposed to be iterating through each one differently in the for loop on the `ax`.

```
# Function to plot all original features and derived features for the activities
def plot(db: np.array, lb: np.array, activities: dict, binwidth: float):
    df_data = create_plot_df(db, lb, activities)
    columns = columns_name[:-1] if db.shape[2] == 6 else ['ACC', 'GYRO'] # vectorized data only has 2 OG features

    for i in range(db.shape[2]):
        # Structure the data
        data_subset = df_data.loc[df_data['original_feature'] == columns[i], ['values', 'activity', 'derived_feature']]

        # Order the data_subset
        order_of_derived_features = ['MEAN', 'STANDARD_DEVIATION', 'ABSOLUTE_MAXIMUM', 'ZERO_CROSSING_RATE', 'SIGNAL_ENERGY']
        data_subset['derived_feature'] = pd.Categorical(data_subset['derived_feature'], categories=order_of_derived_features, ordered=True)
        data_subset = data_subset.sort_values('derived_feature')

        # Plotting
        plot = sns.FacetGrid(data_subset, col='derived_feature', hue='activity', height=4, aspect=1.2, col_wrap = 5)

        for ax, (derived_feature_label, group_data) in zip(plot.axes.flat, data_subset.groupby('derived_feature')):
            lower_limit = np.nanpercentile(group_data['values'],5)
            upper_limit = np.nanpercentile(group_data['values'],95)

            ax.set_xlim(lower_limit,upper_limit)

            ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(ScalarFormatter())
            plot.add_legend()

        plot.map(sns.histplot, 'values', element='step', log_scale=True, binwidth=binwidth, alpha=0.3)
        plot.set(xscale='log', yscale='log')
        ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(ScalarFormatter())  # sets x-axis to decimal
        plot.add_legend()

        plt.suptitle(f'Original Feature: {columns[i]}', y=1.02)

    plt.show()
```

for reference:

- `db` is np.array of shape divided in [values, derived_features,
  original_features]
- `lb` is np.array of labels for each value
- `activities` is a dict for the activities names
- `create_plot_df` : structures the dataframe

```
def create_plot_df(db : np.array,lb : np.array , activities: dict):
    _, n_derived_features, n_original_features = db.shape
    normalized_db = add_minimum(db)

    columns = columns_name[:-1] if db.shape[2] == 6 else ['ACC', 'GYRO']

    # Initlialize the Dataframe
    df_data = pd.DataFrame(columns=['values', 'activity', 'derived_feature', 'original_feature'])

    for original_feature in range(n_original_features):
        for derived_feature in range(n_derived_features):
            if db.shape[2] == 6 or (db.shape[2] != 6 and derived_feature != 3):
                # Add the data to the Dataframe
                values = normalized_db[:, derived_feature, original_feature]
                activity = np.vectorize(activities.get)(lb)
                derived_feature_label = derived_features_labels[derived_feature + 1]
                original_feature_label = columns[original_feature]

                df_temp = pd.DataFrame({
                    'values': values,
                    'activity': activity,
                    'derived_feature': derived_feature_label,
                    'original_feature': original_feature_label
                })

                df_data = pd.concat([df_data, df_temp], ignore_index=True)
    return df_data
```

[image: Created Plots]

Comment: By default, [sns.FacetGrid](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.FacetGrid.html) sets `sharex=True` (as well as `sharey`). If that isn't desired, you can set `sns.FacetGrid(..., sharex=False)`. (By the way, calling the return value something like `g` would ease comparing your code to tutorials and other example code. It is also recommended to use `for  derived_feature_label, ax is g.axes_dict.items():` to make sure the same order is used for features and axes.)